# dataframe.apply() while keeping columns names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply, data-science

I want to apply a function on every row in the dataframe. I am using apply() but then it passes a Series object, therefore the columns names are not passed. Is there a way to use .apply() and keep columns names?

Comment: add code and example

Comment: The column names *are* passed if you use `axis=1` in `pd.DataFrame.apply`.

Comment: The column names because it is a Series end up in the as the series name, if apply over axis=1 or as the series index if apply over axis=1.

Comment: @ScottBoston, One of them should probably be `axis=0` ?

Comment: I do not think you need `apply` here

Answer (score 2):

if you want to apply the function row wise:

for each row in the data frame you want to pass that entire row to a function, and within the function you want to call values using column names then you can do it this way:

```
# df

    name value
0   AA  1
1   BB  2
2   CC  3

def  function_2(row):
    return row['value'] * 2

df['col_b'] = df.apply(lambda row: function_2(row), axis=1)
```

output:

```
    name value col_b
0   AA  1   2
1   BB  2   4
2   CC  3   6
```

[Example source Link](https://github.com/vi3k6i5/pandas_basics/blob/master/2_b_apply_a_function_row_wise.ipynb)